# Switch dojox AutoRotator animation

Tags: javascript, animation, dojo

The [rotator](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/widget/AutoRotator.html) allows/requires you to choose which animation to use to transition from one pane to the other (Pan*, Slide*, Wipe*, ...). Problem is, if I choose "PanLeft" for "next pane" initially, there seems to by no way to use "PanRight" for "previous pane". It's completely unintuitive seeing the same animation played for either direction. I tried changing the rotator object's "transition" property string after creating the object, but that changed nothing. It still kept playing the animation it had been initialized with.

Since there are often undocumented features in dojo, is there are way to actually do it anyway? Or will I have to think of something else completely?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you just need to use `dojox.widget.rotator.Pan` instead of `dojox.widget.rotator.PanLeft`.